# 2009 Macbook A1278 with only win10 loaded, need mac os x but cant install it?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, macos

I was sold a Macbook a1278 and it only has some weird version of windows 10 on it (Everything is all red and inverted colors and the os seems to be all messed up). I tried doing many different things and I have a USB with mountain lion ready to install but nothing is working. What can I try? It has no mac os x utilities or anything at all. I tried booting up internet recovery and the computer fan just spins and black screen..

Comment: An 09 Mac won't be able to use internet recovery; nor probably boot from USB. You'll need a DVD, or take it to an Apple Store, they'll do it for free

Comment: I am going in tomorrow thank you I will update once I am back.

Answer (score 1):

Boot into recovery mode and if that doesn't exist wipe the entire disk and then boot using the USB drive.
You can wipe the disk by removing it from the macbook if recovery mode doesn't work.

Comment: I tried recovery it doesn't work. How do I wipe the disk and then boot it in USB?